# How can I make my button in Python Tkinter clickable?

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, button, tkinter

I'm trying to create a feedback form using Tkinter in Python. For now I am writing for it to show a message box if the name entry is '' when clicked on the submit button. But the button cannot be clicked and is disabled. How can I fix this?

```
# import all functions from the tkinter   
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
  
# import messagebox class from tkinter  
from tkinter import messagebox 
  
# Create a GUI window  
root = Tk()

# create a function to check input
def  check_input():
    if name_input == '':
        messagebox.showerror("please enter your name") 

# create the input entry
name_input = Entry(root)
age_input = Entry(root)
phone_input = Entry(root)
email_input = Entry(root)

# label  the input entry
name_label = Label(text="Username")
age_label = Label(text="Age")
phone_label = Label(text="Phone")
email_label = Label(text="Email")

# display the input entry
name_label.grid(row = 1,column = 1, padx = 10)
name_input.grid(row = 2,column = 1,padx = 10)

age_label.grid(row = 3,column = 1,padx = 10)
age_input.grid(row = 4,column = 1,padx = 10)

phone_label.grid(row = 5,column = 1,padx = 10)
phone_input.grid(row = 6,column = 1,padx = 10)

email_label.grid(row = 7,column = 1,padx = 10)
email_input.grid(row = 8,column = 1,padx = 10)

# create the submit button
submit_button = Button(root,text="Submit",command = check_input)

# display the submit button
submit_button.grid(row = 9,column = 1,padx = 10)

        
# Start the GUI   
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when button is disabled? for me, everything works fine

Comment: when you say "can't be clicked" do you mean it does nothing? `name_input` is a Tk `entry` object so it will never be equal to an empty string, so the command will never do anything as it is written.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `get()` method to get contents from an Entry:

```
# create a function to check input
def  check_input():
    if name_input.get() == '':
        messagebox.showerror("please enter your name")
```

Answer (score 0):

[![tested and shows no error][1]][1]

your button is clickable and is visible ... there maybe some other issue with your requirements but button works
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQqH3.png

if you want to get value from the textbox your need to set text variable for entry
like

```
ttk.Entry(win,textvariable=hexanum).grid(column=1,row=0)
```

then if you need to get values from text box you'll be doing something like

```
inhexa=(hexanum.get()) #hexanum is the textvariable associated to entry/textbox 
                       #inhexa is a variable in which the value from get function is stored (if need to store)
```

do your homework :) feel free to ask

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't have to use a `textvariable` to get a value out of the entry widget.